# JQuery- document.ready function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, popup

I am building a website (Static HTML Website). In my index page, I have an image slider. I used JQuery for that. On clicking any image, that will pop up. And there is a link, for which I used another JQuery function. On clicking that link, a window will pop up. But the problem is that I am not able to use both of them at the same time. I defined both the functions inside

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

Is it because of that??

Comment: may be you should share the code.

Comment: Any Conflict in your console?

Comment: can you share code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

Is just making sure nothing inside get's fired before the whole page is loaded.

I think you could get much more specific help if you would post the whole code.